# Implementing a Social Sharing in Ionic using cordova plugins

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement social sharing in ionic. I followed this tutorial https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-social-media-sharing-ionicframework/

I'm getting the error as

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

```
at Object.share (ng-cordova.min.js:9)
at Scope.$scope.shareAnyWhere (shareController.js:10)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21037)
at ionic.bundle.js:53344
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23093)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23192)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53343)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11706)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
```

I have install the plugins which was mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Try `$ ionic plugin list` and check is the above plugin listed ?

Comment: cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

Comment: @NehilMistry is SocialSharing pluging is added.

Comment: @aorfevre I have gone through the link. Followed all the instruction. But I was not successful.

Comment: show us the list of plugin of your app : "cordova plugin"

Comment: Are you trying this on your browser?

Comment: @keval I'm using ionic view for testing.

Comment: nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.18 "SocialSharing"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"                                                      
         org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
         org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
         org.pbernasconi.progressindicator 1.1.0 "Progress Indicator"
         @aorfevre plugins I have added

Comment: please use social share plugin in device only. it won't work in browser. So please use android or ios device for your test.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you include ng-cordova before cordova.js. Then take a look at the working example [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/), try that.

Secondly, Make sure you are doing your tests on a real device or on an emulator, Social sharing plugin is intended for native sharing functionality on the OS you are targeting, it is not intended and it will not work on the browser. If you are on a browser then that is why!

You can use the [Ionic CLI](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) to run your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **window.plugins.socialsharing** object and call the functions like **shareViaFacebook** etc ..this is working for me right now in all my projects.

For more details and full code you can check the video here [Social Sharing Plugin: Ionic App](http://technotip.com/4809/social-sharing-plugin-ionic-app/)